# Review queue side-by-side diff broken when wide image is present

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

Wide images break the side-by-side view when reviewing posts.

[Link to review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6214443). Screenshot below.

[image]

---

And another one ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6218374))

[image]

And [another](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6312829), awful one:

[image]

Comment: ++ that's a pretty serious bug...

Comment: This is also [network wide](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/side-by-side-view-overlap), I believe

Comment: @Clive: good point. I wish there were an easy way to migrate one's own MSO questions to MSE when it becomes clear that they have network-wide relevance.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett for bugs that is not needed, those tags are watched and reported across all sites.

Comment: Just got the same one while reviewing. Isn't this a matter of changing the `overflow` on the wrappers of versions compared?

Comment: A year later, the problem [remains unsolved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10377215).

Comment: And another year later, [still the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285025/280883)

Comment: Came across [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/15329317) This is an [easy fix](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341819/layout-bug-in-the-side-by-side-view-in-review), devs!