# Layout bug in the side-by-side view in Review

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

(I'm not sure if this error exists across all Review Queues, or just the Reopen Queue)

When in the Reopen review queue just now, I noticed [a closed post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/14924184) that had an image overflowing the width of the column:

[image]

As you can see, there's plenty of space for the two columns here, if you just spread them out.

Adjusting the CSS (across a couple files) to the following would give more room without expanding the standard 1060px column everything sits in. And I can't imagine an issue with the sidebar text overflowing, as the values below are about as wide as they would ever be:

```css
#mainbar, .mainbar { /* all.css */
    #width: 850px;
}
#revisions .sidebyside-diff > div { /* this style is set inline */
    width: 395px !important;
}
#sidebar, .sidebar { /* all.css */
    width: 200px;
}
```

The above styles would net you a view like this:

[image]

Comment: @Tanner Really? I searched for like 15 minutes for an existing question -_-

Comment: lol - it came up in the sidebar under related links when I viewed this post. I didn't find it, it found me.